# Do ILNumerics .NET Visualization Engine support the following features regarding 3D surface chart?

Tags: ilnumerics

I would like to know whether the following features are supported in .NET Visualization Engine of ILNumerics

1. Draw a 3D Surface Plot
2. Layout a wireframe over the Surface Plot
3. Draw a scatter plot over the Surface Plot
4. Color the surface using custom values and show the color bar as a legend.
5. Custom meshgrid with support for floating point values.
6. Able to Zoom, Pan and Rotate the plot
7. Tooltip support together with the ability to select a point from the Surface plot (maybe using mouseclick/crosshair etc). I need a callback function from the point selected.
8. Modify axis properties such ticks, labels, titles etc.
9. Lighting and Shading options in the chart.

Please do reply

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all is supported. Start with the visualization documentation: http://ilnumerics.net/Visualization-API.html

The [examples section](http://ilnumerics.net/examples.php) contains many runnable examples, including [this one](http://ilnumerics.net/examples.php?exid=973e55c00307a98fb62fb97f4f1f3bff) dealing with mouse picking on 3D surface plots.